babel.config.js file not being created react native
Im currently new to react native and im following up on the docs but while running the npx create-expo-app@latest, i realised that the babel.config.js file is not being created. I have tried looking for a solution to it through the net and docs but i came out empty handed. Anyone have a clue on how to solve this issue?
here is my package.json


{
  "name": "slade",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^7.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "expo": "~52.0.7",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.2",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-symbols": "~0.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-native-webview": "13.12.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~52.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}




If your project requires a custom Babel configuration, you need to create the babel.config.js file in your project by following the steps below:

Navigate to the root of your project, run the following command
inside a terminal


npx expo customize


This command prompts generating different config files. Select
babel.config.js.

The babel.config.js file is created in the root of your project with
the default configuration as shown below:
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);
return {
presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
};
};


Expo Docs
