babel.plugin.js file missing
I am making a project on expo sdk using npx create-expo-app@latest but it keeps making the project without the babel.plugin.js file. Is there a specific reason for that? I have tried multiple times but still I cannot resolve this issue.
I tried to delete the projects and make them again but still can not find a way to resolve this.

Please check this would answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79194781/babel-config-js-file-not-being-created-react-native
